# Force SSL with exceptions in web.config

Tags: iis, web-config

I currently have the following in a web.config to force SSL, however I need to exclude specific paths from being forced.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS From HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've tried changing the `match url` to have the specific path inverted but it appears to not get caught.

Examples:

site.com/app/default.aspx - force SSL
site.com/app/service/cashback.svc - not forced, HTTP only
site.com/app/service/different.svc - force SSL (so it's not the full directory that has to be excluded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your exceptions to `<conditions>`, e.g.

`<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" negate="true" pattern="/app/service/cashback\.svc" />`

Comment: I had to change `REQUEST_URL` to `REQUEST_URI` however this worked a charm. Thanks